# Scala: Option[Seq[String]] vs Seq[Option[String]]?

Tags: scala

I'm creating a method to retrieve a list of users from a database by ID.

I'm trying to decide on the pros and cons of declaring the `ids` parameter as `Option[Seq[String]]` vs `Seq[Option[String]]`?

In what cases should I favour one over the other?

Comment: Why don't just use Seq[String]? What do you intend to do with None values?

Comment: These values come in from an API that gives me `Seq[Option[String]]`. I could map over those and build a new list I guess and then just pass in `Seq[String]`. This method itself won't do anything with None values though.

Comment: "I could map over those and build a new list I guess and then just pass in Seq[String]"
You can just flatten it: Seq(Some("a"), None).flatten

Comment: Oh that sounds better. OK I think you've answered my question. Use Options if you're want to do something different with None values. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual this strongly depends on the use case.

A `Seq[Option[String]]` will be useful if the size of the sequence is relevant (eg., because you want to zip it with another sequence).

If this is not the case I would opt for flattening the sequence in order to just have a `Seq[String]`. This will likely be a better choice than `Option[Seq[String]]`, as the sequence can also be of zero length.

In fact an `Option` can usually be treated as if it where an array that can have either length zero or one. Therefore wrapping an `Iterable` in an `Option` often only adds unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 3):

A list of users in neither well represented as an `Option[Seq[String]]` nor as a `Seq[Option[String]]`. I would expect something like a `List[User]` as a list of users. Or maybe a `Vector` or `Seq`

If your string represents your user, and the None case does nothing, you could consider filtering those out. You can do this with

```
val dbresult: Seq[Option[String]] = ???
val strings = dbresult collect { case Some(str) => str }
```

or

```
val strings = dbresult.flatten
```

but it's difficult to give good advice without knowing what the `Option[String]` or `Option[Seq]` represents